# How to enable a minor mode immediately after a buffer is open?

Tags: variables, minor-mode, pdf-tools

I have been using a pdf-tools fork with a image-roll.el support, this fork and file make it possible to scroll continuously from the end of a page to the beginning of the other without jumping from end of page to beginning of the next page, and I got it to work with my emacs, but there is a downside that to make it operational I always have to go to the buffer where my pdf is being displayed and in that buffer type `M-x pdf-view-roll-minor-mode` and after this it works very well, I am new to emacs and lisp, but is there a way to make this command automatic whenever I open a pdf-tools buffer?

I mean, in the documentation it seems as if `pdf-view-roll-minor-mode` is a variable that begins with the value nil and there is something about toggle and positive and negative values, can't I change the value of this in the init.el and have it always on and working whenever I open a pdf view buffer?

Comment: Have you tried `(ad-hook 'pdf-view-mode #'pdf-view-roll-minor-mode)` in your init file ?

Comment: Hello, I didn't know what hooks were but I have tried to put this code in my init file and it gave me an error about the function definition being void in add-hook.

Comment: There are a couple of typos in that suggestion.  I've added an answer with the corrected config.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, in the documentation it seems as if `pdf-view-roll-minor-mode` is a variable

Any minor mode symbol is both a command function and also a variable, where the command enables or disables the mode, and the variable indicates the current state of the mode.

Invoking the command with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `pdf-view-roll-minor-mode` would toggle the state.

Command functions can also be called in code, and the normal approach to your question is to use a "mode hook" to do that:

```el
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook #'pdf-view-roll-minor-mode)
```

Which essentially says "after enabling `pdf-view-mode` call the function `pdf-view-roll-minor-mode`".

Note that <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `pdf-view-mode` tells you:

> In addition to any hooks its parent mode `special-mode` might have run,
> this mode runs the hook `pdf-view-mode-hook`, as the final or penultimate step
> during initialization.

and if you inspect that hook variable with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `pdf-view-mode-hook` you'll observe your configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!